# Delete Objects in Core data using cascade Relationship

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, ios5

Hi i am having Category entity and Subcategory Entity i need to when i delete Category Object at the same time subcategory object also delete here (Category----> Two-many relation ship and set to cascade) and subcategory(set nullify)so in category entity i am having two methods

```
- (void)addDeletionObject:(SubCategoryEntity *)value;
- (void)removeDeletionObject:(SubCategoryEntity *)value;
- (void)addDeletion:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeDeletion:(NSSet *)values;
```

can any one please guide me how can i delete the subcategory that related categoryId when will i use the methods.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `[context deleteObject:category];` and your related `SubCategory`s Will be deleted as Will if you have set the delete rule to cascade for Category. Don't forget to save.